# c++ : The if statement not functioning correctly and proceeds to Invalid output

Tags: c++, if-statement, char, comparison-operators

Just started learning c++ and trying to make an automated ordering system but while trying to run before continuing working with it i'm encountering this problem :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char acoustic, fender, hartwood, electric, gibson, ibanez, drums, pearl, 
roland, piano, casio;
char rolandpi, equip, string, headphone, amp, mixer, micro, tuner, pick, 
music, Yes, No;

int pay1 = 0, pay2 = 0;

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the Music Shop" << endl <<endl;

    cout << "a. Acoustic Guitar" << endl;
    cout << "a.1 Fender Acoustic Guitar   - P6,900.00" << endl;
    cout << "a.2 Hartwood Acoustic Guitar - P6,300.00" << endl <<endl;

    cout << "b. Electric Guitar" << endl;
    cout << "b.1 Gibson Electric Guitar   -P8,500.00" << endl;
    cout << "b.2 Ibanez Electric Guitar   -P25,000.00" << endl <<endl;

    cout << "c. Drums" << endl;
    cout << "c.1 Pearl Drum Kits          -P27,000.00" << endl;
    cout << "c.2 Roland Electronic Drums  -P24,000.00" << endl <<endl;

    cout << "d. Piano" << endl;
    cout << "d.1 Casio Digital Piano      -P19,000.00" << endl;
    cout << "d.2 Roland Piano             -P120,000.00" << endl <<endl;

    cout << "e. Music Equipments" << endl;
    cout << "e.1 Guitar String            -P113.00" << endl;
    cout << "e.2 Headphones               -P1,600.00" << endl;
    cout << "e.3 Amplifier                -P2,800.00" << endl;
    cout << "e.4 Digital Mixer            -P4,750.00" << endl;
    cout << "e.4 Vocal Microphone         -P860.00" << endl;
    cout << "e.5 Guitar Tuner             -P537.00" << endl;
    cout << "e.6 Guitar Pick              -P360.00" << endl <<endl;

    cout << "Choose the music instrument or equipment you want to buy: ";
    cin >> music;

    switch (music)
    {
        case 'a':

        cout<< "Acoustic Guitar" << endl;
        cout<< "1. Fender Acoustic Guitar   - P6,900.00" << endl;
        cout<< "2. Hartwood Acoustic Guitar - P6,300.00" << endl <<endl;
        cout<<"Choose from the available Acoustic Guitars:";
        cin>>acoustic;

        if (acoustic == 1){
            cout<<"Enter your payment:";
            cin>>pay1;
            if (pay1=6900){
                cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Fender Acoustic Guitar"<<endl;
            }
                else if (pay1>6900){
                    pay1 -= 6900;
                    cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay1<<endl;
                }
                    else (pay1<6900);
                    {
                        cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                    }
        }
        else if (acoustic == 2){
            cout<<"Enter your payment:";
            cin>>pay1;
            if (pay1=6300){
                cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Fender Acoustic Guitar"<<endl;
            }
                else if (pay1>6300){
                    pay1 -= 6300;
                    cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay1<<endl;
                }
                    else (pay1<6300);
                    {
                        cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                    }
        }
        else {
            cout<<"Invalid"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I already checked my `if else` statements and can't find whats wrong.

After inputting `1` or `2` from "Choose from the available Acoustic Guitars" it keeps proceeding to "invalid".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read in a `char` here:

```
cout << "Choose from the available Acoustic Guitars:";
cin >> acoustic;
```

But then you compare it with an `int` one line later:

```
if (acoustic == 1) {
```

Instead this should be:

```
if (acoustic == '1') {
```

Also this:

```
if (pay1 = 6900) {
```

Should be:

```
if (pay1 == 6900) {
```

Because otherwise you will get incorrect output regardless of what is entered, because `pay1 = 6900` sets `pay1` to `6900` and returns `6900`, which is implicitly converted to `true`.

Also this line:

```
else (pay1 < 6900);
```

Needs to be changed to

```
else if (pay1 < 6900)
```

Because otherwise `(pay1 < 6900)` isnt' the condition of an `if` statement, but instead `(pay1 < 6900);` is what happens in the `else` case (which just calculates a boolean and discards it), causing the following `"You do not have enough money"` message to always be printed.

Comment: Thanks for that also i noticed that i placed ; after the else (pay1<6900) coz otherwise the You do not have enough money output keeps on showing but after removing it now im getting the [Error] expected ';' before '{' token

Comment: @Student right, I oversaw this one. I edited my post and inserted how this `else` line should look like, and why it's currently not behaving properly.

Comment: thanks for that, i got additional question below if u dont mind

Answer (score 0):

@Blaze thank u so much now im almost done, now im getting a problem with the Yes or No after inputting Yes the program just ends and i dont know whats wrong with it >.<

```
cout<<"\nWould you like to buy an Electric Guitar?"<<endl;
    cout<<"Yes or No?"<<endl;
    cin>>answer;

    if (answer == Yes){
    cout<< "Electric Guitar" << endl;
    cout<< "1. Gibson Electric Guitar   -P8,500.00" << endl;
    cout<< "2. Ibanez Electric Guitar   -P25,000.00" << endl <<endl;
    cout<<"Choose from the available Electric Guitars:";
    cin>>electric;

        if (electric=='1'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay2;
        if (pay2==8500){
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Fender Acoustic Guitar"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay2>8500){
                pay2 -= 8500;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay2<<endl;
            }
                else if(pay2<8500)
                {
                    cout<<"You do not have enough money"<<endl;
                }   
    }
    else if (electric=='2'){
        cout<<"Enter your payment:";
        cin>>pay2;
        if (pay2==25000)
        {
            cout<<"You have succesfully purchased Fender Acoustic Guitar"<<endl;
        }
            else if (pay2>25000){
                pay2 -= 25000;
                cout<<"Your change is:"<<pay2<<endl;
            }
                else if (pay2<25000)
                {
                    cout<<"Invalid"<<endl;
                }   
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Invalid";
    }
} 
    else if (No){
        cout<<"Thank you for checking our other products";
}
}
}
```

Comment: If you have further questions you should post them separately, not as answers to your previous question. Anyway, this snippet doesn't compile even with the previous code (there is no declaration of `answer`). You could try `std::string answer;` and then change  `if (answer == Yes){` to `if (answer == "Yes"){`. `else if (No){` doesn't make sense in this context, it should probably be `else if (answer == "No"){` followed by an `else` to catch all other cases.